# window.ethereum not injecting in metamask in-app browser on android

Tags: android, metamask

I tried getting ethereum to inject onto my dApp loaded on the metamask in-app browser. At times, it works but at times not. More often not. It works fine on ios but on android it gives problems. Can anyone help me?

I tried setting a timeout and an event listener but each time i run the application window.ethereum comes up an undefined

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.